# Lock no SQL Server e Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Olá, estive efetuando alguns testes de lock no SQL Server e observei uma diferença em relação ao Oracle.

No oracle eu fiz um update em uma linha sem efetuar `commit` ou `rollback` e em outra sessão eu consegui consultar a linha tranquilamente, e é claro, eu vizualizei o dado anterior (consistente) e não o novo valor que ainda não foi comitado.

Fiz o mesmo teste no SQL Server porém ao efetuar a consulta na outra sessão ele ficou aguardado o `commit` ou `rollback` da linha que está sendo atualizada e diferente do Oracle não me retornou o valor consistente. 
O mecanismo de lock do SQL Server sempre trabalha assim?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, ao contrário do Oracle, no SQL Server se você não especificar um bloco de comandos dentro de uma transação `BEGIN TRAN` e a operação demorar, é possível que terceiros vejam uma situação inconsistente antes do término das operações.

Ou ainda, insira `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` no início do script SQL e todas as operações dentro dele serão transações. Isso simula exatamente o comportamento do Oracle. Mas não esqueça de efetuar `COMMIT` ou `ROLLBACK` ao final, liberando o lock.